# How to get a list of native Oracle Functions Like (NVL, ABS etc)

Tags: oracle

I've trying with this command bellow, but does not work as i expected:

```
select OBJECT_NAME, OWNER from SYS.ALL_OBJECTS where upper(OBJECT_TYPE) = upper('FUNCTION') order by OWNER, OBJECT_NAME
```

is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: I would not expect a query for database functions to show native language functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this one:

```
select distinct PROCEDURE_NAME
from ALL_PROCEDURES
where OWNER = 'SYS'
    and OBJECT_NAME = 'STANDARD';
```